# Add a column based on condition met in other columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I am new to PySpark and I ma currently facing challenge in the following problem. 
I have a spark `df` as follows

```
DeviceID     max(A)    max(B)    max(INUT)
0023002      2.5       3.7       8.1
0023045      2.2       1.3       11.3
0023008      4.7       2.3       1.9
```

How I want to add another column as 'Status' where the values would be based on following logic.

```
if 0.20 * max(INUT) > max(max(A),max(B)) then Status = 'Imbalance' else 'Balance'
```

The above logic is expected to produce the following dataframe.

```
DeviceID     max(A)    max(B)    max(INUT)    Status
0023002      2.5       3.7       8.1          'Balance'
0023045      2.2       1.3      11.3          'ImBalance'
0023008      4.7       2.3       1.9          'Balance'
```

Now to achieve the above `df`, below is the code I am using

```
from pyspark.sql.function import col
import pyspark.sql.function as F
df_final = df.withColumn(
             'Status',
             F.when(col('max(INUT)')*0.20 > F.greatest(col('max(A)'),col('max(B)'),
             'Imbalance')\
         .otherwise('Balance')
```

The above code snippet is throwing an error as

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'otherwise'
```

Where am I missing out? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: missing ) at end?

Comment: oh it was typo. even if I close with `))` still I am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some little syntax errors here is your final code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
[("0023002", 2.5, 3.7, 8.1),
("0023045", 2.2, 1.3, 11.3),
("0023008", 4.7, 2.3, 1.9)], ["DeviceID", "max_A", "max_B", "max_INUT"])

df_final = df.withColumn('Status', \
             F.when(F.col('max_INUT')*0.20 > F.greatest(F.col('max_A'),F.col('max_B')), 'Imbalance') \
         .otherwise('Balance'))
```

And some comments/remarks:

1. To use the functions from `pyspark.sql.functions` just use F alias. You dont need to import it twice.
2. There were some missing parenthesis
3. I also replaced `max(A) -> max_A` since it makes it easier to read I believe

Output:

```
+--------+-----+-----+--------+---------+
|DeviceID|max_A|max_B|max_INUT|   Status|
+--------+-----+-----+--------+---------+
| 0023002|  2.5|  3.7|     8.1|  Balance|
| 0023045|  2.2|  1.3|    11.3|Imbalance|
| 0023008|  4.7|  2.3|     1.9|  Balance|
+--------+-----+-----+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks. Regarding point 3:  Is it necessary to change the name of the column from `max(A)`to `max_A`? I am asking because, the name of the column was derived from another dataframe via an iterative process.

Comment: No, it was just confusing me since it looks like a func call :)

Comment: Although you can always rename you columns with `withColumnRename` on dataframe or with `alias` on Column types